# How to set more than one page in django

Tags: python, django

After I code more than one page in url.py and run it.I can't the page I want see.The browser show me "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".By the way,when I have only one page,it works.I need someone help me,thanks. My code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.views import *

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), 
  url(r'^hello/',hello), 
]
```

The file name "views": 
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    import datetime
    def hello(request):
      return HttpResponse("Hello World")

```
def now(request):
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
  return HttpResponse(html)
```

When I visit the root directory,terminal show:
    Not Found: /
    [15/Jun/2017 15:14:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2022

But I visit the hello page it didn't give me any hints.The browser show me "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

Comment: post your views, and stacktrace

Comment: The file name "views":
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def hello(request):
  return HttpResponse("Hello World")

def now(request):
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
  return HttpResponse(html)

Comment: yes views.py and also the error in the terminal

Comment: post it in the question not comment and the stacktrace in the terminal when you go to the url in webpage

Comment: When I visit the root directory,terminal show:
Not Found: /
[15/Jun/2017 15:14:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2022

But I visit the hello page it didn't give me any hints.

Comment: its impossible for anyone to help you if you dont post your views.py settings.py and stacktrace in the question, why dont you edit the question and put the codes

Comment: Sorry,I'm a new  newbie.I can't understand something.Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: no thats ok, tell me do you have an app called mysite? or your project name is mysite?

Comment: Yes，my project name "mysite".After I start this project I only create the “views.py”in dictionary "mysite,and I modify “urls.py” as the question show.

Comment: you cannot do it like that, create an app and in that apps views you need to write the code, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/ follow this tutorial, you will understand

Comment: Oh I follow the Chinese tutoral,it told me do that.I try again and follow this.Thank you for your explanation！